# Sync folder with Android device

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, android

I would like to have a folder with all my music which is automatically synced on my Android device (Wifi only, plugged in only, like in SugarSync). Is there any hope for this feature to be implemented in the near future.

This would actually make me pay for U1.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the application [FolderSync Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite&hl=en) and a UbuntuOne account to sync one or more folders between a Ubuntu machine and your Android device.

The application allows syncing either way, or two-way, and does work for entire folders.
The application also supports many other cloud services, like Dropbox and Box.net.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup Dropbox at http://www.dropbox.com. Dropbox allows you to sync files and folder between Mac, PC, Linux, Android, and iOS.

Comment: Thanks that i go info of Ubuntu One Android sync beeing payed. Solved timesaving. Good that i didnt deleted Dropbox account and still using linking to dropbox folder

Comment: Unfortunately the native Android Dropbox client does not support automatic folder sync. Furthermore when I am going to pay for a cloud service I would like to support Ubuntu (especially since Dropbox charges $ 10 per month).

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a client for ubuntu one files available in the android market...you can set it so it will only sync when connected to wifi...you just have to select the folder you want to sync to your phone using the app

Comment: I know the client, but it does not support folder sync, like the Desktop version.